# Testing radius server from Mac OS X client

Tags: networking, radius, 802.1

I have a radius server set up on a server running Ubuntu 11.04.  I have configured my switch to use the authentication server's IP (192.168.1.2) for RADIUS / 802.1x authentication, and I created a connection to test connecting from my Mac OSX client.

Here is my radius configuration for the client:

```
client 192.168.1.0/16 {
  secret = testing123
}
```

I can successfully authenticate using both 127.0.0.1 (localhost) and 192.168.1.2 (ip of eth1), so I know radius is getting those requests.

I set up a connection to test from my macbook, and my requests are timing out.

http://screencast.com/t/tMhRLS3H7

Is there a better way to test the radius connection from my macbook?  Thanks!

**UPDATE:** 
I was able to successfully test on Mac OSX client using [RadPerf](http://networkradius.com/radperf.html).  This is available as a cross-platform command line tool.

Comment: I realise this question was closed a long time ago. But I don't suppose you still have a copy of radperf available? The networkradius.com website gives an error when you try to register for a download:/

Comment: This question was never closed, and nobody has yet provided an answer.

Answer (score 10):

FreeRadius provides a tool called [`radtest`](https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v3.0.x/src/main/radtest.in) that sends a RADIUS packet to a server, asking it to authorize a request with a username and password provided on the command line:

```
radtest username password radius-server[:port] nas-port-number secret
```

To install `radtest` on OS X, install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/%20Brew):

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)
```

The installer will probably prompt you to do a few things, such as install Xcode, run `brew doctor`, or run `brew update`. Finish the install and then run:

```
$ brew install freeradius-server
```

Once Homebrew finishes installing FreeRadius, `radtest` should be available for your use:

```
$ radtest username password 192.168.1.2 10 secret
```

---

A few notes.

1. The `10` is the request's NAS-Port attribute. In most cases, it doesn't matter what you set for the NAS-Port, so long as its a reasonable port number.
2. The commands above will install FreeRadius 2.0.6 on your computer, but if you're interested in version 3.0.7, run `brew install --devel freeradius-server`. (This may change in the future as FreeRadius progresses to a v3.1, v3.0, and v2.0 versioning system.)
3. `radtest` is a front end for `radclient`, which should also be available after you install FreeRadius. If you want more sophisticated testing abilities, check out the `radclient` man page for more details.